# GCM push notifications for Titanium (Android)

Tags: javascript, mobile, titanium, google-cloud-messaging

I use "iamyellow" GCM push notifications for Titanium but Titanum SDK 4.0.1 not supported this module.

Are there any other way you suggest? Do you have another way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's some new modules out there implementing GCM which should work:
http://gitt.io/search?q=gcm